# The reason why IllegalArgumentException error about array length in this for loop

Tags: java, algorithm

My program looks like this:
The input array is [1,2,3,4], the target is 7 and the output should be [2,3]

```
public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
    Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    // nums.length-1 why is cannot be minus 1
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length-1; i++){
        int result = target - nums[i];
        if (map.containsKey(result)){
            return new int[]{i,map.get(result)};
        }
        map.put(nums[i],i);   
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No result.");
}
```

There will be error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no two numbers in the list can add to the target.
    at Solution.twoSum(Solution.java:12)
    at __DriverSolution__.__helper__(__Driver__.java:8)
    at __Driver__.main(__Driver__.java:54)
```

But change the search length by plus 1, there will succeed.
The correct code is like this

```
public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
    Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    // the correct answer is no minus 1 in i < nums.length
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
        int result = target - nums[i];
        if (map.containsKey(result)){
            return new int[]{i,map.get(result)};
        }
        map.put(nums[i],i);   
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No result.");
}
```

Can anyone help me why this happens, why could not use minus 1 here 
`i < nums.length`

The number 12 line is

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("No result.");
```

Comment: error message indicates that the error is at line 12, would be helpful if you told us which line was no. 12. also, edit your post with the correct code

Comment: @Abby One doesn't need a line number to identify the line in the method that throws this method. That part is absolutely obvious. The only open question here is *why* that throws is there.

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is straight forward:

```
if (map.containsKey(result)){
  return new int[]{i,map.get(result)};
```

will *abort/break/end* the enclosing method.

In other words: when a certain condition is met, the method stops within the loop.

If that condition is **never** met, then the loop is repeated, and then, that hardcoded, unconditional *throws* kicks in.

Given the edit to the question: the point here is that you wrote some pretty hard to understand code. The naming of your variables doesn't tell us anything about their intended usage.

I can only repeat what was said: this code implements *some* sort of algorithm. The algorithm is supposed to identify those two indexes in an input array that added together result in some "target sum". The algorithm uses a map that uses

- a value from the input array as map key
- the *index* of that value as map value

It seems that when you don't iterate to the very end of the indexes, you miss a correct condition and therefore throw.

But the real answer isn't *me* telling you what *your* code does. The *real* answer is that you either use a debugger to understand what your code does, or to take a piece of paper and a pen to manually run your code.

Again: this is your code, it is doing what *you* put into code, so you should step back and slowly, step by step dive into it to understand what exactly it is doing.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote a mistake in the question. The question is about the comment line.